# I do not understand in a process of proving that $|H-E|=|Z|=0$ iff $|E=H-Z|$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Notation

$|E|_e$ is the outer measure of $E$.

$|E|$ is the measure of $E$.

A type $G_\delta$ means countable intersection of open sets.

---

The theorem is
$$
E \text{ is measurable if and only if } E=H-Z\text{, where }H \text{ is of type } G_\delta \text{ and } |Z|=0.
$$

---

Proof

$(\leftarrow)$

1. Since open set is measurable, so is $H$.
2. Since $H$ and $Z$ are measurable, $E$ is measurable.

$(\rightarrow)$

1. Choose an open set $G_k$ such that $E\subset G_k$ and $\left|G_k - E\right| \lt \frac1k$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
2. Set $H=\bigcap_kG_k$. Then $E\subset H$.
3. Since $H\subset G_k$, we have $H-E \subset G_k-E$.
4. Hence, $|H-E|=0$ since $|H-E|\le|G_k-E|\lt\frac1k$ for all $k$.
5. These follows if $E$ is measurable, then $E=H-Z$.

---

I understand almost all but process 5.

Can someone explain process 5? I don't know why $|H-E|=|Z|$ means $E=H-Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E \subset H$, we have
$$E = H -(H - E)$$
So we can take $Z = H - E$. You have already shown that $Z$ has zero measure.

Comment: Aren't there any problems to peel out $|\cdot|$?

\begin{align}
|E| &= |H-(H-E)| = |H|-|H-E| ~~~\left(\text{since } H \text{ and } H-E \text{ are disjoint.}\right)
\end{align}

$$
\therefore |H-E|=|H|-|E|=|Z|=0
$$

I understand until here. But I do not understand why it means that $$H-E=Z$$

Comment: @Danny_Kim No, there is nothing in the problem statement that requires $|E| = |H| - |H - E|$, so we don't need to show this.

Comment: Thanks to you, I understand until $|H|-|E|=|Z|$. Now I wondered how to peel measure symbols out.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Do you agree that for any sets $E \subset H$ we have $E = H - (H - E)$? (regardless of measurability - this is just an elementary set-theoretic statment).

Comment: Yes, I understood that $E=H-(H-E)$.

Comment: OK, so if we define $Z = H - E$ then we have $E=  H - Z$. And in step 4, you showed that $|Z| = |H-E| = 0$. So we have $E = H - Z$ where $Z$ has zero measure, as desired.

Comment: I agree that if $Z=H-E$, then $|Z|=|H-E|=0$. However I have to show that if $|Z|=|H-E|=0$, then $Z=H-E$, don't I?

Comment: @Danny_Kim No, you don't have to prove $Z = H-E$, we have defined it that way.

Comment: Ah!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I realized!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are genius Good Thank you!!